# Domain admin profile stuck on login to server

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-firewall

Thank you in advance for reading this, I appreciate it.

I recently built a new AD for the company I work for. Everything was going good. All of a sudden my profile is getting stuck on welcome screen. When I disable windows firewall DOMAIN NETWORK on the DC I have no issues with login but when I turn on windows firewall DOMAIN NETWORK my profile and other AD profiles get stuck.

I tried to see if there is a GPO I enabled that's causing this but I did not find anything. Mostly everything is at default, very little GPO's are enabled and it has nothing to do with login.

Is there any rule I need to create on windows firewall?

Comment: What Network and Firewall profiles are active?

Comment: So on the domain controller I have Domain Network turned OFF and Private, Guest or Public network is turned ON. I am using Windows Firewall to turn ON/OFF

When I turn ON domain network I cannot login, it just gets stuck.